# Convergence in mean square from expected value/variance

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm looking for a proof of the following statement: Given a sequence of independent random variables $X_n$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} E[X_n] = T,
$$
where T is a constant, then
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} V[X_n] = 0
$$
implies convergence of $X_n$ to $T$ in the mean-square.  This statement is supplied without proof or reference in Shreve's Stochastic Calculus book.

Comment: @t-laarhoven: "Mean-square" convergence means $L^2$ convergence, i.e. we want to show $E[(X_n - T)^2] \to 0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume $V[X_n]$ is the variance.

Let $\mu_n = E[X_n]$ for convenience, and write
$$\begin{align*} E[(X_n - T)^2] &= E[(X_n - \mu_n + \mu_n - T)^2] \\ &= E[(X_n - \mu_n)^2] + (\mu_n - T)^2.\end{align*}$$

(The cross term vanished since $E[X_n - \mu_n]=0$.)  Now both terms go to 0 by assumption.

Comment: Hmm, this is very simple.  I think my mind was rebelling at the implication that this implies almost-sure convergence for a subsequence of ${X_n}$.  The latter fact seems too good to be true...

Comment: By the way, this is why $E(X)$ is the value of $x$ which minimizes $E((X-x)^2)$ (and why, as a consequence, the minimal value is the variance of $X$).